# I need an algorithm to concatenate 2 vectors and also update the vector in cases of common element in C++ (not specific to C++11)

Tags: c++, string, vector, concatenation

I have 2 vectors say vector of string/char.

`vector<string> dest` having elements `{"Demo01","Demo02","Demo03"}`

`vector<string> src`   having elements `{"Demo03","Demo07","Demo08"}`

I want to copy all the elements from src to dest such that if dest vector already has an element present in src vector, replace that element in the dest vector with string "Demo03Duplicate"
If no common elements found, just copy it in the dest vector.(there can be more than one common element)

End result:

`vector<string> dest` having elements `{"Demo01","Demo02","Demo03Duplicate","Demo07","Demo08"}`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No, I need to work with std::vector only

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Due to the fact that you can not assume that any of those two vectors has only unique elements, and you are not allowed to loose duplicated entries, your suggestion is not be valid, is it?

Comment: That's what I doubt as well @luantkow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple approach would be to just check for every element in `src` vector, if an duplicate exists in `dest` vector or not. If it exists just append `Duplicate` to it, else you can just push back the element as a new element in dest vector.

The follow code would do the job -

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string>src = {"Demo01","Demo02","Demo03"};
    vector<string>dest = {"Demo03","Demo07","Demo08"};
    //loop for every element in src, check if exists in dest 
    for(int i=0;i<src.size();i++){
        bool flg=true;  
        for(int j=0;j<dest.size();j++){
            //if duplicate found, append "duplicate" and set flg to false so we don't push_back later on
            if(src[i]==dest[j]){
                dest[j] += "Duplicate";
                flg = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if no duplicates, then insert from src to dest.
        if(flg)
            dest.push_back(src[i]);

    }
    sort(dest.begin(),dest.end());
    for(auto el:dest)cout<<el<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

That would be the brute force approach. Maybe there exists some better approach than this, but this approach would do the job as well.

Comment: You kind of swapped the vectors as per the question but got the idea what you are trying to explain

Comment: What would happen if there are two duplicates is `src[]`?

Comment: @Damien duplicate won't be matched, since when we find the first occurence of duplicate, we append duplicate to it

Comment: It is what I understood. Then the second duplicate will be appended. Not clear for me what OP wants in this case